# Unity load Certificate from Windows Store

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, x509certificate2

I want to load a certificate from local windows certificate store.

With UWP my code looks like the following and I can fetch my certificate:

```
public static X509Certificate2 ClientCertificate()
{
    X509Certificate2 cert = null;
    X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
    for (int i = 0; i < store.Certificates.Count; i++)
    {
        cert = store.Certificates[i];
        if (cert.Thumbprint == "68c8e9abc4b950a88701047af543a94c61c9ae38".ToUpper())
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return cert;
}
```

When using Unity 2019.4 I get an error message in line `store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);`, saying:
`System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Store My doesn\'t exists.`

What am I doing wrong with my Unity-code that I cannot access certificates from local windows certificate store?

Comment: Have you wrapped your code in the appropriate `#if` preprocessor directives, such as `UNITY_WSA` or `UNITY_UWP`? Are you trying to build for the appropriate platform?

Comment: No, I have not wrapped it around preprocessor directives. The code also runs on regular C# projects that are not UWP. Do I have to wrap it up? I'd like it to run on all unity platforms, is there another way to safely store and fetch certificates in Unity?

Comment: Those directives are part of the uwp platform so they won't run on other platforms, so yes you do have to wrap it. However, you only have to wrap those parts that won't work across platforms. Most of your game code won't need to be wrapped like that. Just anything that references any API in a platform-specific namespace. You can test this by changing your build target to something else.

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this?

Comment: @Reahreic Unfortunately I gave up on the project, Unity's Mono just had too many features missing I was using before.